# Adding CKEditor to Django project

Tags: python, django, web, django-admin, ckeditor

Could someone please guide me in the proper direction to install CKEditor in my Django project? I'm very new at this, so the more thorough of a explanation, the much more helpful it will be for me.

I found this link, but it isn't working very well for me: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install ckeditor
```

1. Add -ckeditor- in setting of your project [installed apps]

#### Admin CK Editor for video embedding

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = root('uploads')
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Advanced',
        'width': 758,
        'height': 300,
    },
}
```

#### Admin CK Editor for video embedding

2. Create a folder uploads inside the project
3. Add this url in your main `urls.py`

   ```
   url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
   ```
4. Add this in to your models.py

   ```
   from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
   content = RichTextField(verbose_name='BlogContent',null=True,blank=True)
   ```

Make sure do `python manage.py collectstatic` before running your project.

Answer (score 6):

There is another way of integrating CKeditor to Django by using Javascript version of CKeditor.

Download ckeditor from http://ckeditor.com/download and extract the zip file, put the unzipped folder in static root. add ckeditor static files to your template like:

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

In your form, add html class like this:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):

    text = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attr={'class':'richtexteditor'})
```

And to make this rich text editor visible, add the following line your template:

```
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( '.richtexteditor' );
</script>
```